# Can Laravel models be MULTIPLE polymorphic types?

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, polymorphism

If a `user` table has a polymorphic relationship like the following:

**Users:**

`- id
- userable_id
_ userable_type`

And the **User types** can be:

`- App\Student
- App\Teacher`

**QUESTION:** How do we handle a user that can be *BOTH* a student and a teacher? This would happen if a teacher decides to take a lesson from another teacher (perhaps a different topic). We will need to store unique information for this user related to a teacher and a student.

Perhaps this is a case where we just add (nullable) `teacher_id` and (nullable) `student_id` columns to the user table?

Thanks,

Comment: teacher_id and student_id is one way of handling this and if you don't foresee any other additional user types, that may be the best way.  I probably wouldn't use polymorphism if I only had two firm types, but if types can expand in the future: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: Edit: Many-to-many polymorphism...of course! I think I'll stick with the teacher_id and student_id for now. The other types are more like roles that won't need unique information (admin, etc). Thank you for the quick reply, Devon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good article for polymorphism is https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/modeling-polymorphic-associations-in-a-relational-database.

Using a teacher_id and student_id is one way of handling this and if you don't foresee  additional user types, that may be the best way.  This type of relationship is referred to as Exclusive Belongs To.  It is expandable, but it requires an additional column for each type.

Laravel uses the Polymorphic Joins type of relationship.  It can easily expand and handle many types, but lacks some referential integrity.  If types can expand in the future, and users can belong to many types, you'd want a many to many polymorphic relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

I probably wouldn't use polymorphic joins if I only had two firm types.  I'd rely on the first method (Exclusive Belongs To) and use independent relationships for each type.